# Error in the use of DotNetZip

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

Why errors?

```
                        using Ionic.Zip;

                        ZipPath = textBox7.Text + "Instructions.zip";
                        ExtractPath = textBox7.Text;

                        var ExistingZipFile = ZipPath;
                        string TargetDirectory = ExtractPath;

                        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
                        {
                            foreach (ZipEntry es in zip)
                            {
                                es.Extract(TargetDirectory, true);  // overwrite == true
                            }
                        }
```

> The error 2 Most suitable overloaded method for
>   "Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Extract (string,
>   Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction)" has several inadmissible
>   arguments of E:\Install\Form1.cs 494 37 Install the Error 3 Argument
>   "2": type conversion from "bool" to
>   "Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction" is impossible for
>   E:\Install\Form1.cs 494 65 Install

If I Uberall rewriting errors no - es.Extract(TargetDirectory);

Comment: @DarkBobG corrected

Comment: The error is saying the second argument to `es.Extract` requires an object of type `Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction` (which seems like an enum), but you're passing in a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a boolean as the second parameter. But the type is a enum of type Ionic.Zip.ExtractExistingFileAction.

Please try and change your code to:

```
        using (ZipFile zip = ZipFile.Read(ExistingZipFile))
        {
            foreach (ZipEntry es in zip)
            {
                es.Extract(TargetDirectory, ExtractExistingFileAction.OverwriteSilently);  // overwrite == true
            }
        }
```